# executor memory and local deployment

Tags: apache-spark

When adjusting the memory for the executors (e.g., by setting `--executor-memory 2g`) and setting for the master a local deployment (`local[4]`), does each local thread receive 2 GB of memory or are the 2 GB set in total for the local run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spark.executor.memory` is set per executor process and this amount is shared between executor threads.

Comment: so you say that if I set executor-memory to 2 GB thats all the whole deployment will get?

Comment: Yes. In local mode there is only one executor (and JVM in total).